# Android alert dialog won't open in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have been trying to debug the issue of an alert dialog not opening on click of an image button when certain options in a spinner are selected.

The below is my MainActivity.java file which includes the relevant code for the alert dialog (left out code for the spinner as this is working as intended), any help would be much appreciated!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialise Inputs & Fields
        this.UnitSelector();
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.options_spinner);

        // UI Relationships
        ImageButton tapeButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton_tape);

        Log.d("SpinnerValue", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();

        // Listeners & Actions
        tapeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
//                float messageFloat = Float.parseFloat(message);
                Log.d("Button Clicked", spinnerValue);
                if (spinnerValue == "Kilogram" || spinnerValue == "Celsius"){
                    createDialog("Nah mate", "Okay", MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

void createDialog( String title, String msg, Context context){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder
                = new AlertDialog
                .Builder(context);

        // Set the message show for the Alert time
        builder.setMessage(msg);

        // Set Alert Title
        builder.setTitle(title);

        // Set Cancelable false
        // for when the user clicks on the outside
        // the Dialog Box then it will remain show
        builder.setCancelable(true);


        builder.setNeutralButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });


        // Create the Alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the adapter

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.options_spinner);

        String[] values = {"Kilogram","Celsius","other"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        ImageButton tapeButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton_tape);

        tapeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (spinnerValue.equals("Kilogram") || spinnerValue.equals("Celsius")){
                    createDialog("Nah mate", "Okay", MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have the spinner adapter code in my main activity already and that works as intended. But your answer gave me the hint I needed. It looks as though the condition in the if statement wasn't using the equals function but "==" instead. This solved my issue! Thank you!!